# Chrome Extensions i18n: Redirecting to locale-specific content

Tags: google-chrome, internationalization, locale

Question: How can I redirect users to most-relevant content, sitting in 3 different sub-directories, depending on their preferred language?

**What I have**

I have created 3 different _locales sub-directories, each containing language-specific messages.json files:

- _locales/en/messages.json
- _locales/en_GB/messages.json
- _locales/de/messages.json

In manifest.json in the root directory, this already works well and as expected to correctly adapt the extension's name and description in the respective language, using:

*manifest.json*

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "__MSG_extensionName__",
  "description": "__MSG_extensionDescription__",
  "version": "1.0",

  "default_locale": "en",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "__MSG_extensionName__",
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

**Where I am stuck**

As the user clicks on my extension's icon, I also want to load language-specific content from the most-relevant sub-directory -- instead of the "default_popup": "popup.html" line -- because some URLs that I link to from the popup.html files also differ by language:

- _locales/en/popup.html
- _locales/en_GB/popup.html
- _locales/de/popup.html

So I thought the best way to do it is to exchange that one line from my root manifest.json that currently reads

```
"default_popup": "popup.html"
```

with a line that reads

```
"default_popup": "__MSG_initialContent__"
```

and then within each of the _locales sub-directories' messages.json files have

```
"initialContent": {
    "message": "popup.html"
}
```

so that it reads the content locally from within that subdirectory.

BUT: That is where it all falls apart. Then I get a "This webpage is not found error".

I have tried, to no avail, these differing variations (examples below for _locales/de/messages.json) -- all leading to the same error message:

```
"initialContent": {
    "message": "popup.html"
}
```

then

```
"initialContent": {
    "message": "_locales/de/popup.html"
}
```

then

```
"initialContent": {
    "message": "/de/popup.html"
}
```

and lastly

```
"initialContent": {
    "message": "de/popup.html"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is very old but I just found it and I guess it would be nice for future visitors to get a solution.

What you need to achieve this are ["Predefined messages"](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/i18n#overview-predefined)

Quote:

> **Predefined messages**
>
> The internationalization system provides a few predefined messages to help you localize. These include **`@@ui_locale`**, so you can detect the current UI locale, ...
>
> [...]
>
> The special message **`@@extension_id`** can be used in the CSS and JavaScript files, whether or not the extension or app is localized. This message doesn't work in manifest files.
>
> The following table describes each predefined message.
>
> **`@@extension_id`**
>   The extension or app ID; you might use this string to construct URLs for resources inside the extension. Even unlocalized extensions can use this message. 
>   Note: You can't use this message in a manifest file.
>
> **`@@ui_locale`**  The current locale; you might use this string to construct locale-specific URLs.
>
> [...]